# Get grayscale image directly from webcam using Opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, webcam, grayscale

Since in my embedded application I need images in grayscale, in order to save time I'm trying to get a frame from the webcam directly in grayscale without getting it from RGB format conversion.

The examples that I've found gets the frame in RGB and then converts it with

```
cvCvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess (really just a guess) without conversion you can only take what the camera gives to you. If that's really an important time critical point in your processing, there is a trick: you could just use a single channel of your RGB/BGR image and interpret that as your grayscale image.

Comment: Hi Micka, thanks! I will try. But just one question: let's suppose that the dominant channel in my current image is blue, while red contains much less informations. If, just for examples, I always consider red channel only, I would loose much of the information. Is this correct?

Comment: yeah sure, but it depends on your task.
I've seen people using just one channel instead of computing a "real" grayscale conversion (grayscale conversion is btw an artificial combination of the channels, but empirically found to be how people percept color) because in their scenario it was sufficient.

Comment: btw, care which conversion you use. Normally OpenCV manages images in BGR order, so `CV_BGR2GRAY` might be more appropriate!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, simply use the `v4l2-ctl` command to reduce all saturation and get the camera to spit out grayscale output:

```
 v4l2-ctl -c saturation=0
```

Of course, that will work only if your webcam supports the `saturation` option. To check whether it does, take a look at all available controls:

```
v4l2-ctl -l
```

Comment: Just to confirm, does this actually make the camera return grayscale data? E.g. data from the camera is 1/3 the size? (My context is reducing USB bandwidth). This is not just postprocessing?

Comment: The manual states that the tool controls video4linux devices. I would assume this means the hardware, i.e. the thing you plug into the USB port. So I would further assume and expect a reduction in bandwidth. If you could test this by profiling the I/O bandwidth, the community would be interested in your findings.

Answer (score 1):

In short, NO!

Most of the camera output are in YUV formats. The videoCapture function converts this to RGB. 
`cvSetCaptureProperty` function can be used to set the value of `CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB` flag as FALSE.
Thus the output will be in YUV. Converting this image to gray scale image.

By doing so, we could avoid the YUV-to-RGB conversion. And the YUV-to-Gray conversion is computationally less intensive as Y-channel is indeed the gray data.
I am not so sure, will have to give it a try.

Comment: nice idea, unfortunately not supported by any of my off-the-shelf-webcam

Comment: I too tried it out. It seems like the current V4L library doesn't support this flag. It just acts blind to this flag :(